# Kotlin coroutines mvvm return value from model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, coroutine

I'm making a crawling logic by using coroutines in Kotlin but i don't know this code is right.

this is model class

```
  suspend fun parseYgosu() : Elements? {
    var data:Elements? = null

    var x : Deferred<Elements?> = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        var doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ygosu.com/community/real_article").get()
        data = doc.select("div.board_wrap tbody tr")
        data
    }
        x.await()
    Log.d(TAG, "$data")
    return data
}
```

This code have problems. I do not want it be a suspend function.
And also I want to get data from this function by calling it from repository class.
could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`liveData` builder](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)

```kotlin
fun parseYgosu(): LiveData<Elements?> = liveData {  
    val element = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Jsoup.connect("https://www.ygosu.com/community/real_article")
            .get()
            .select("div.board_wrap tbody tr")
    }
    emit(element)
}
```

and UI side:

```kotlin
// for fragment
viewModel.parseYgosu().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { element -> ... })
// or for activity
viewModel.parseYgosu().observe(this, Observer { element -> ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the future Deferred, if you don't want it to be suspend then you can't have `await()` in it

```
// Not suspend
fun parseYgosuAsync() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
    val doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ygosu.com/community/real_article").get()
    val data = doc.select("div.board_wrap tbody tr")
    Log.d(TAG, "$data")
    data
}
```